# Access ElastiCache redis from a private EKS Cluster

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-eks, amazon-elasticache

I have an EKS cluster and trying to connect the application pod to the ElastiCache Redis endpoint. Both are in the same VPC. I allow the communication between both EKS and ElastiCache Redis.

When I telnet from a pod to the ElastiCache Redis endpoint is connected. But Unfortunately, I access from my nodejs application in won't work.

Can somebody help me to resolve this?